# New columns with groupby condition not working in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df=
['user_id','session_id','purchase']
[1,34,'yes']
[1,35,'no']
[2,36,'no']
```

Now, I want to create a 2 new columns which sums up all purchases for each user. Note that for the same user, it should paste the same value in those new columns like this:

```
df=
['user_id','session_id','purchase',purchase_yes','purchase_no']
[1,34,'yes',1,1]
[1,35,'no' ,1,1]
[2,36,'no' ,0,1]
```

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
df['purchase_yes'] = df[df.purchase == 'yes'].groupby("user_id").purchase.sum()
```

It shows me Nan values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `value_counts` to obtain the sum:

```
a=df.groupby(['user_id'])['purchase'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print(a)

purchase    no  yes
user_id     
1            1    1
2            1    0
```

Then using [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['purchase_yes']=df['user_id'].map(a['yes'])
df['purchase_no']=df['user_id'].map(a['no'])
```

Output:

```
   user_id  session_id purchase  purchase_yes  purchase_no
0        1          34      yes             1           1
1        1          35       no             1           1
2        2          36       no             0           1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = df.groupby('user_id').purchase.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)

# you can also use either of these
# new_df = pd.crosstab(df.user_id, df.purchase)
# new_df = df.pivot_table(index='user_id', columns='purchase', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0)

# rename the columns of new data
new_df.columns = 'purchase_'+new_df.columns

# merge the new data with the old on user_id
df.merge(new_df, left_on='user_id', right_index=True)
```

output:

```
   user_id  session_id purchase  purchase_no  purchase_yes
0        1          34      yes            1             1
1        1          35       no            1             1
2        2          36       no            1             0
```